# three congruent circles intersect each other, bounding two shaded regions

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Three circles of the same radius intersect other so that the center of one circle is on the circumference of the others, as shown. I want to draw this shading with tikz.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a MWE: you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate (Y) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (X) at (210:2.5cm);
   \coordinate (Z) at (-30:2.5cm);
   \fill[gray]  (X) circle (2.5cm);
   \fill[white] (Y) circle (2.5cm);
   \begin{scope}
      \clip  (Z) circle (2.5cm);
      \fill[gray]  (X) circle (2.5cm);
   \end{scope}

   \foreach \pt in {X,Y,Z} {
     \draw (\pt) circle (2.5cm);
     \fill[black]  (\pt) circle (2pt);
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just for reference:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\tikzset{random fill/.code={%
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{rnd}\pgfmathsetmacro\g{rnd}\pgfmathsetmacro\b{rnd}%
\definecolor{.}{rgb}{\r,\g,\b}%
\tikzset{fill=.}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={random fill}]
\path (0:0)   arc (150:90:1)  arc (30:150:1)  arc (90:30:1) -- cycle;
\path (0:0)   arc (30:-30:1)  arc (210:150:1) -- cycle;
\path (150:1) arc (90:330:1)  arc (270:150:1) -- cycle;
\path (30:1)  arc (90:-150:1) arc (270:390:1) -- cycle;
\path (0:0)   arc (30:90:1)   arc (150:270:1) arc (210:150:1) -- cycle;
\path (0:0)   arc (150:90:1)  arc (30:-90:1)  arc (-30:30:1)  -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With `tkz-euclide` just to show variety:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=pink!40},
                        show background rectangle,rotate=-10]
     \tkzDefPoint(0,0){Y}
     \tkzDefPoint(210:2){X}
     \tkzDefPoint(-30:2){Z}
     \tkzFillCircle[color=gray!40](X,Y)
     \tkzFillCircle[color=white](Y,X)
     \begin{scope}
       \tkzClipCircle(Z,Y)
       \tkzFillCircle[color=gray!50,%
          opacity=.5](X,Y)
     \end{scope}
     \tkzDrawCircle(X,Y)
     \tkzDrawCircle(Y,X)
     \tkzDrawCircle(Z,Y)
     \tkzDrawPoints[color=blue,fill=blue](X,Y,Z)
     \tkzLabelPoints[right](X,Y,Z)

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]